# CakePHP - Select box item not properly appearing in POSTED data

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following select box with CakePHP.

```
//Users/settings.ctp

$options = array('NYC', 'LA');      

    echo $this->Form->create('Location');
    echo $this->Form->input('Location', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options)); 
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

In the UsersController I have

```
public function settings($id = null){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $location = $this->request->data;
        //$location = $location['Location']['Location'][0];
        $this->Session->setFlash( __(print_r($location))); //displays '1' in the alert no matter the selection
    }
}
```

When I use print_r on the raw data it shows the following.

```
Array ( [Location] => Array ( [Location] => 0 ) )
```

So I have two problems

1. The index of the item is being selected, not the item itself
2. The setFlash window always displays '1'. I need to do some string manipulation after I get the listbox working and it's nice to see the output.

**update - I went into /Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php and did some digging**

I did a print_r on the following line

```
$attributes = $this->_initInputField($fieldName, array_merge(
        (array)$attributes, array('secure' => self::SECURE_SKIP)
    ));
```

Which resulted in

```
Array ( [value] => 0 [class] => [name] => data[Users][Location] [id] => UsersLocation )
```

The value being passed is 0, I don't see the location anywhere

Comment: Don't debug inside a setFlash, rather just do a `debug($this->request->data)` to see what data was posted.

Comment: It's the same as print_r which I listed above. It sends the index, not the item.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a form for the "Location" model, but you need to specify which field the select is for:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Location.location', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options));
```

Or, if it's not actually for the "Location" model, then either replace the "Location" in the form `create()` with the correct model, or use `null` if it's not a model at all:

$this->Form->create(null);

Comment: Didn't work. By the way, this is part of UsersController. I don't have one for location, so if anything it would be Users model. However, why is it getting the index but not the item? It's obviously seeing the data if the selected index is properly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and decided someone else might find it useful so.

The array needed to be formatted as

```
$options = array(
   'value' => 'Display');
```

So, I used

```
$options = array(
    'NYC' => 'NYC',
    'LA' => 'LA');
```